# Python for .net 64 bit installation

Tags: python, .net, c#-4.0, ironpython, python.net

I recently installed python for .net on my 64 bit machine. I followed the instructions from https://github.com/geographika/PythonDotNet. I copied the files from `/PythonDotNet202_py27_net4_x64` to `C:\Python27\DLLs`.
However, when I do import clr, I got the error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The python I have is 64 bit. It looks like it is complaining the clr is 32 bit. However, I got the `clr.pyd` from the x64 folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to install pythonnet using pip: `pip install pythonnet`. The official repo is located at github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: If you decide to copy manually, then place both `Python.Runtime.dll` and `clr.pyd` to `python\Lib\site-packages` directory.